# How to turn a Pandas DataFrame into a table of vectors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vector, transformation

I have a two columns Pandas data frame containing a list of user_ids and some URLs they have visited. It looks like this:

```
    users   urls
0   user1   url1
1   user1   url3
2   user1   url5
3   user2   url2
4   user2   url4
5   user2   url5
6   user3   url1
7   user3   url4
8   user3   url5
```

I want to create a vector representation of itself, like this:

```
        url1    url2    url3    url4    url5
user1   1.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0
user2   NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0     1.0
user3   1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0
```

I've tried different things, but keep hitting a wall. Any ideas?

Comment: check out `pd.get_dummies(df)`. Also, don't post questions with images as inputs, it makes it harder for people to help you

Comment: And please do not post images. SO now allows to have nice tables in the question, formatted as text so that we can easily copy their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a pivot of the url column

```
# Make data
df = pd.DataFrame([
               ['user1', 'url1'], 
               ['user1', 'url3'], 
               ['user1', 'url5'],
               ['user2', 'url2'],
               ['user2', 'url4'],
               ['user2', 'url5'],
               ['user3', 'url1'],
               ['user3', 'url4'],
               ['user3', 'url5']
               ], columns=['users', 'urls'])
# add column to fill pivoted values
df['count'] = 1

new_df = df.pivot(index='users',columns='urls',values='count').fill_na(0)
new_df

# urls   url1  url2  url3  url4  url5
# users                              
# user1   1.0   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
# user2   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
# user3   1.0   0.0   0.0   1.0   1.0
```

This puts the users column in the index, but you can use reset_index to make it a regular column again.

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your problem with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
               ['user1', 'url1'], 
               ['user1', 'url3'], 
               ['user1', 'url5'],
               ['user2', 'url2'],
               ['user2', 'url4'],
               ['user2', 'url5'],
               ['user3', 'url1'],
               ['user3', 'url4'],
               ['user3', 'url5']
               ], columns=['users', 'urls'])
```

I applied a for loop for my solution. I am sure someone more competent than me can find a more elegant solution.

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for user in np.unique(df['users']):
   s = pd.get_dummies(df[df['users']==user]['urls']).sum()
   s.name = user
   new_df = new_df.append(s)
new_df
        url1    url3    url5    url2    url4
user1   1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
user2   NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0     1.0
user3   1.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0
```

If your want your columns to be ordered you can simply apply this:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=np.unique(df['urls']))
```

Which initializes the new dataframe to have your unique urls as columns.

```
        url1    url2    url3    url4    url5
user1   1.0     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0
user2   NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0     1.0
user3   1.0     NaN     NaN     1.0     1.0
```